# Mapping topic back to documents in Spark LDA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, lda

I have loaded a number of Reuter news wire articles (1986) into Spark 2.2 and want do some topic learning using LDA

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|               title|                body|  id|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+
|FED SAYS IT SETS ...|                    |5434|
|MIM TO ACQUIRE ST...|Mount Isa Mines H...|5435|
|MAGNA <MAGAF> CRE...|Magna Internation...|5436|
|J.W. MAYS INC <MA...|Shr 2.27 dlrs vs ...|5437|
```

I have set up a pipeline

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, stopWordsRemover, vectorizer, lda))
```

run the model

```
val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(corpus)
```

I can access the LDA (EM) model using

```
val ldaModel = pipelineModel.stages(3).asInstanceOf[DistributedLDAModel]
```

I can see the topics using

```
ldaModel.describeTopics(maxTermsPerTopic = 5).show()
```

which after a bit of DF manipulation, it gives topics and their associated terms and probabilities

```
+-------+----------+--------------------+
|topicId|      term|         probability|
+-------+----------+--------------------+
|      0|   company| 0.08715003585328869|
|      0|      corp| 0.03355461912220357|
|      0|     group|0.024083945559541863|
|      0|      unit|0.016712655949244752|
|      0|     stake| 0.01314416068270042|
|      1|      dlrs|   0.072961342546073|
|      1|      debt| 0.02826491264713813|
...
```

i want to map the topic distribution back to the original documents. Back in Spark 1.6 to the get the topic distribution for the document (id=5435) above, i would do the following. But topicDistributions is no longer supported.

```
 ldaModel.topicDistributions.filter(_._1 == 5435).collect
```

The (Spark ML LDA API) does list two new methods but i am unclear how to use them

```
 final val topicConcentration: DoubleParam
```

and 
     final val topicDistributionCol: Param[String]

Had anyone done this?

Comment: I meet the same question. The following answer does not work. Do you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but it looks like you just want to `transform`:

```
ldaModel.transform(corpus)
```

Comment: Your solution worked as provided here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda, 
thank!